# Do the official Advaita Shankaracharya Peethams reject the teachings of Vivekananda as heretical?

Tags: vivekananda, neo-vedanta

Do the official Advaita [Shankaracharya Peethams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sringeri_Sharada_Peetham) reject the teachings of Vivekananda as heretical?

Answer (score 8):

The Sringeri Peethadhipati has a very broadminded approach towards other philosophies and religions. Though he is no doubt an advaitin, he does not reject other doctrines as heretical. Nor does he advocate that everyone should convert to advaita. Here are some of his thoughts -

http://svbf.org/thought-of-the-day

> Conversions from one religion to another is neither advisable nor desirable. **The religion in which a man is born is the best fitted for his spiritual upliftment. The Lord knows which religion is best for us and gives us birth in a country, climate, time and faith for which we are best suited.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> No matter how good an artist is, we cannot paint a picture on vacant air, though he may possess the finest paints and brushes. He requires a stable background, be it canvas or a wall. – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> Similarly a seeker should apply his God given gifts on the stable background of his God chosen faith. **So a Hindu should try to become a better Hindu, a Muslim a better Muslim, a Buddhist a better Buddhist and a Christian a better Christian.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> **Who are we to sit in judgement over other religious teachers and religions? Waste not your precious life in judging others. Use it to regulate your life and purify yourself.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> **There must be perfect equality – each man to his religion – unmolested by anybody and every facility guaranteed to him to practice his own religious pursuit.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> **Every facility must be given for a Hindu to live the life of a Hindu, a Muslim to live the life of a Muslim, a Christian the life of a Christian, and so on.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> **No one on earth, howsoever powerful, has any right to compel the people to change or break their religious laws. No one has the right to interfere in the religious matters of another.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> All religious conflicts and quarrels arise because a devotee is unable to disassociate his conception of God from a particular name and form. – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal
>
> As long as, by a process of analysis, he does not learn to disassociate the name from the thing, the name is the thing for him, and if you deny that name, he will take it that you deny the thing itself. **If you realise that all Gods are one and all paths lead to God, you will never waste your precious life in religious quarrels.** – Chandrasekhara Bharati Mahaswamigal

Based on these quotes, we can infer that the Sringeri Peethadhipathi does not reject the teachings of Swami Vivekananda as heretical.

Comment: It seems that Swamijigal is very familiar with Swami Vivekananda's thoughts.

Comment: Great answer. My sincere respects to the great Mahapreyiva!